# Disable localhost_access_log from tomcat kubernetes container

Tags: kubernetes, tomcat, dockerfile

I have an application in a Tomcat9 container with Kubernetes. I want to disable localhost_access_log-yyy-mm-dd.txt from /usr/local/tomcat/logs. I know that there is a possibility, to comment from server.xml this part:

```
`<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />`
```

But If I try to make a sed in Dockerfile,and to comment that part when I start the container, it will end in Error status. Is there any possibility to make this without touching server.xml?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you really need to override config with `sed`, as `sed` might be a way in pure dockerized environment but why sed when there is a better option available through configmap in Kubernetes .

create a configmap from server.xml file

```
kubectl create configmap server-config --from-file=server.xml
```

and server.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

and the deployment file with configmap volume

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tomcat-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tomcat
  replicas: 1 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tomcat
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: tomcat
        image: tomcat:latest
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config-volume
          mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
      volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: server-config
```

Comment: So I have a dockerfile that use a tomcat image and I already have an application with a configmap deployed in a kubernetes container using that dockerfile and It is not very clear for me your solution. I am a beginner. Thanks